# How to make lm display in its output a formula passed to it as a variable

Tags: r

Please consider the following example code (from the `lm` doc):

```
ctl <- c(4.17,5.58,5.18,6.11,4.50,4.61,5.17,4.53,5.33,5.14)
trt <- c(4.81,4.17,4.41,3.59,5.87,3.83,6.03,4.89,4.32,4.69)
group <- gl(2,10,20, labels=c("Ctl","Trt"))
weight <- c(ctl, trt)
lm(weight ~ group)
form1 <- weight ~ group
lm(form1)
do.call("lm",list(formula=form1))
```

With the following (abbreviated) output:

```
> lm(weight ~ group)

Call:
lm(formula = weight ~ group)

> lm(form1)

Call:
lm(formula = form1)

> do.call("lm",list(formula=form1))

Call:
lm(formula = weight ~ group)
```

As you can see, the second call to `lm` does not display the formula, but the variable containing the formula. With some experimenting, I came up with the third solution, but I find that one a bit tedious.

**The question hence is**: is there another way to make `lm` display the formula instead of the variable (i.e. without using the `do.call` method I used above).

(The reason I want this is that I am working on a Sweave document, so I cannot see the calls, only the outputs, and then is having lm tell you what formula it used very handy.)

---

**EVEN BETTER SOLUTION** - 
Thanks to @Aaron

```
lm <- function(...) {
  mf <- match.call()
  mf[[1]] <- quote(stats::lm)
  env <- parent.frame()
  mf$formula <- eval(mf$formula, env)
  eval(mf, env)
}
```

**SOLUTION:**
Based on G. Grothendieck's answer, I came up with the following function:

```
lm <- function(...) {
    mf <- match.call()
    mf[[1]] <- quote(stats::lm)
    env <- parent.frame()
    fm <- eval(mf, env)
    fm$call$formula <- formula(fm)
    fm
}
```

Comment: `formula(lm(form1))` gives the model.

Comment: Nice, handy to know. But I would like lm to tell me spontaneously ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put this near the top of your Sweave file:

```
<<preliminaries,echo=FALSE,results=hide>>=
lm <- function(fo, ...) { fm <- stats::lm(fo, ...); fm$call <- fo; fm }
@
```

and then call `lm` normally in the rest of the file.

Using the example in the question and assuming we have defined `lm` as above:

```
> lm(form1)

Call:
weight ~ group

Coefficients:
(Intercept)     groupTrt  
      5.032       -0.371
```

Comment: Thanks! Although you function does not work always, and gives back only the function, and not the complete call, it set me on track. I added my solution to the question.

Answer (score 3):

This might be just as tedious, but at least it contains fewer characters ;)

```
R> eval(call("lm",form1))

Call:
lm(formula = weight ~ group)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)     groupTrt  
      5.032       -0.371
```

Comment: Thanks, indeed an improvement, and still tedious :)

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the `print.lm`:

```
body(print.lm)[[2]] <- 
  as.call(expression({
    ca<-x$call
    ca$formula <- formula(x)
    cat("\nCall:\n", paste(deparse(ca), sep = "\n", collapse = "\n"), "\n\n", sep = "")
  })[[1]])
```

then,

```
> lm(form1)

Call:
lm(formula = weight ~ group)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)     groupTrt  
      5.032       -0.371
```

Comment: Thanks. Works nicely, only I do not use the `print`, but the `summary` function, and after a quick look at its source I decided to go for G. Grothendieck's answer.

Answer (score 2):

A variant based on the OP's final solution (as of Mar 30).

```
lm <- function(formula, ...) {
  mf <- match.call()
  mf[[1]] <- quote("stats::lm")
  env <- parent.frame()
  mf$formula <- eval(mf$formula, env)
  eval(mf, env)
}
```

Comment: More elegant even, modifying the formula in the call instead of in the result. Thanks